# Setting up a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship between two models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So if you had two models, let's say Post and Tag, and you wanted to have one 'primary' tag, and many 'secondary' tags, all coming from the Tag model... is this possible? I can imagine the connections - you'd need a primary tag ID column in the Post Model and a join table for the Secondary tag... but is there any easy way to do this in Rails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you need one join table `post_tags`. This table has column primary to indicate whether it is primary tag. The model should be like as below:

```
class PostTag
  belongs_to :tags
  belongs_to :posts

  # it has primary with type is boolean
end

class Post
  has_many  :post_tags
  has_one   :primary_tag,   -> { where("post_tags.primary": true) }, through: :post_tags, class_name: "Tag"
  has_many  :secondary_tags, -> { where("post_tags.primary": false) }, through: :post_tags, class_name: "Tag"
end

class Tag
  has_many  :post_tags
  has_many  :posts, through: :post_tags
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - it looks like the more straight-forward solution - but I have a concern - if I were to get Tag.all - if someone had a primary tag and a secondary tag with the same name, wouldn't the tag appear in Tag.all twice?

What I really want to do is have the primary/secondary connection on the Post end - so a Tag can be used as a primary tag or a secondary tag.. but it would only be in the Tag table once...

Comment: No, it won't appear twice. A tag can appear multiple times on `post_tags` table because it can be both primary and secondary tag. But it appear only one in `tag` table so that calling `Tag.all` will return only one tag.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, I only just tried to set this up due to a few other issues - it is erroring with `Could not find the source association(s) "primary_tag" or :primary_tag in model PostTag. Try 'has_many :primary_tag, :through => :note_tags, :source => <name>'. Is it one of note or tag?` any ideas?

Comment: @PaulHarker: can you try to change: `class_name: "Tag"` to `source: :tag` on both  `primary_tag` and `secondary_tag`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I can think of, which is easy enough, with the `has_many, through:` being optional depending of what you need.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :tag
 has_many :secondary_tags
 has_many :tags, through: :secondary_tags
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post
 has_many :secondary_tags     
 has_many :posts, through: :secondary_tags
end

class SecondaryTags < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :tag
end
```

Creating the joint table like this:

```
class CreateSecondaryTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :secondary_tags do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :tag_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :secondary_tags, :post_id
    add_index :workout_categories, :tag_id
  end
end
```